# Why is my ES module function undefined sometimes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have the following ES module which initialize a Google Charts.

`mychart.js`

```
let redraw;

function init(data) {
    // Do stuff to populate the chart
    // [...]
    // Set the redraw function which will be called on resize
    redraw = () => chart.draw(data, chartOptions);
    redraw();
    $(window).resize(redraw);
}

export default { redraw, init, [...] };
```

`main.js`

```
import Mychart from './mychart';

$('#specific-button').on('click', function() {
    $('#chart-container').toggle(function() {
        // Also call redraw function when toggling HTML container visible
        if ($('#chart-container').is(':visible')) {
            Mychart.redraw();
        }
    });
});

$.ajax(/* Some ajax query */,
    success: function(data) {
        // First init of the Chart
        Mychart.init(data);
    }
);
```

When my webpage show up, the Chart works and it is correctly resized on `window.resize` event. But when I click the `#specific-button` element it throws me an `undefined` error. What's the way to resolve this?

```
main.js?dbbb:47 Uncaught TypeError: _main_mychart__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.redraw is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you are exporting the object from your module, `redraw` has the value `undefined`. Assigning a different value to the variable later won't update the object. Simple example:

```js
var foo;
var bar = {foo};
foo = 42;
console.log(bar);
```

You can define the object upfront and update the object:

```
const chart = {};

function init(data) {
    // Do stuff to populate the chart
    // [...]
    // Set the redraw function which will be called on resize
    chart.redraw = () => chart.draw(data, chartOptions);
    chart.redraw();
    $(window).resize(chart.redraw);
}
chart.init = init;

export default chart;
```

Or you can use named exports instead (which are "live" bindings):

```
export let redraw;

export function init(data) {
    // Do stuff to populate the chart
    // [...]
    // Set the redraw function which will be called on resize
    redraw = () => chart.draw(data, chartOptions);
    redraw();
    $(window).resize(redraw);
}
```

And in `main.js`:

```
import * as Mychart from './mychart';
```

---

Having said that, a better approach (in both cases) would be to initialize `redraw` with an empty function so that it will always have a proper value (it just won't do anything until the chart was initialized).

Comment: Curious, why is a named export a "live binding", and a default export not a live binding? Don't they essentially accomplish the same thing, it's just one imports everything?

Comment: @p32094: Default exports are also life bindings. The default export is just a named export with name "default".

Comment: Ok so the object I created at first `{ redraw, init, blabla... }` is Life bound but the reference of `redraw` inside that object is wrong?

Comment: @Marc: Yes. When you use a variable to initialize an object property, the current value of the variable is copied into the object. There is no intrinsic connection to the variable the value came from. JavaScript is a "pass-by-value" language (I guess imports/exports are kind of an exception to that).

Comment: I essentially used default exported object (like my code above) in my project, should I consider using Named exports everywhere instead?

Comment: @Marc: It's really up to you. If you are just using the object as a "grab bag" of things to exports, then I would suggest named exports instead.

Comment: @FelixKling That's exactly what I do, so I guess `named exports` + `import * as blabla` is better than `default exported object` in my case?

Comment: @Marc: I would say so. That also allows components to only import what they need, e.g. `import {redraw} from bla`.